# Check if page opening in new window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to determine on server side if user try to open link in new tab. Is it possible?
App use frames, so if I determine it, I could restore frame structure. 
using `this.Request.UrlReferrer == null` works only when user opens a direct link, not for internal page requests.
Also I tried to determine it on client side by javascript, app use frames, so I have check for `window.name == null`, but if page has errors it has been redirected to error page, then script catch that page opening in window with no-frame structure, redirected it to page with frames, and it again redirected to error page, but I couldn't display a correct error, because `Server.GetLastError()` is empty since first redirect. 
So, is it possible to determine that page opening in new window on server side?


For redirect to error page I use `Response.Redirect()`, because after `Server.Transfer()` I couldn't go back and restore previous page form data. So, exception details passing with cookies, *(if redirected with `Server.Transfer()` I can get exception via `Server.GetLastError()`, if redirected with `Response.Redirect()` - `Server.GetLastError()` is null)* and error page displaying them and then clean all cookies.

Comment: On server side! If page throwing exceptions before load - I can not access client side